# achieve "xrandr --set underscan on" with "xrandr --transform"

Tags: xrandr

I'm trying to fit the size of the videoprojector screen to the actual wall size.
there is some option to resize in the projetor's menu itself but it is not sufficient to resize it properly.

I have seen the option of using

```
xrandr --set underscan on
```

but unfortunately that does not work for me, as I have an intel graphics card on my laptop (Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) and I have read that this option is only valid for NVDIA cards.

I have been lead to belive that I may achieve that through a series of command

```
xrandr --transform
```

For example, i've tried doing

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --fb 1800x1000 --transform 1,0,-60,0,1,-30,0,0,1
```

(found from [this page about cropping part of the monitor off](https://superuser.com/questions/1435053/how-to-use-xrandr-to-crop-part-of-monitor-off))

but I am left with the right and bottom part which are unusable on the display.
What I would like to achieve is to rescale the whole screen into a smaller zone, which is still to be determined, possibly playing with some parameters, but for the sake of the example let us imagine that this means reducing indeed the overall size from 1920x1080 to 1800x1000.

How could I then rescale the whole screen instead of cropping part of it off?
Thank you very much for your help.